# Best practice for storage of variant UOM's

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design

I am building an application that will be storing lots of "markers" about people (weight, height, blood pressure, etc.) and as the users will all have different expectations about the units of measure they'd like to measure things in I will need to address UOM's in a smart way. What I'm wondering is if there is any consensus on how to best store this information. Examples that I'm considering are as follows (in each case the frontend is assumed to capture both the marker and the UOM associated with the capture):

1. **Metric Conversion**. Convert to the metric equivalent and store what the original UOM was but only the metric measurement (the original measurement is not lost although possibly some decimal precision in the conversion could creep in)
2. **Store Both**. Store marker, captured UOM, and then convert to metric and store that too. This makes for easy "like-for-like" SQL queries on the metric quantities while perfectly preserving the precision of the original marker but it is clearly more storage intensive. I guess there's also a slightly higher cost to inserts as the conversion to metric needs to be done (but I'd guess this is inconsequential).

For me the precision loss isn't going to be critical except for the jarring user experience that it could create. Imagine if a user puts in 160lbs and then sees it reported back as 159.99lbs; that would be quite disconcerting and would lead people to not believing in the system. I suspect that in most conversions though I would be able to arrive back at the same number without needing to increase the size of precision in the DB too much. This feeling though is just my sunny optimism rather than something I've tested.

Comment: Just a brief comment on your last paragraph. You should be storing the values as floating point to attain the most precision. This means your example would be converted from kg to lbs as something like 159.9999 lbs which when displayed in a format of {0.##} would still be appear as 160. You definitely don't want to be using a fixed point (e.g. decimal) as the database column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing both feels like a bad idea. You have to make sure these values remain consistent and it contravenes the DRY ([don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) principle.

You're confusing storage and presentation. If you're storing a weight then you should store as one representation and then present in whatever representation is required by the user (e.g. kilos, tonnes, tons, grams, stones, lbs, ounces etc.)

You *could* store the units along with the magnitude (e.g. 10 kilos, 4 stone etc.) but that'll make comparisons problematic e.g. SQL queries for entities less than 2 ounces would have to perform conversions. I think performing the UOM conversion upon presentation is a consistent and intuitive solution.

Comment: Ok, I like this answer and it's what my old normalisation training agrees with. As I've gotten back into programming after a decade absence I do notice that there's more and more acceptance and even promotion of de-normalisation at the data storage level which was contributing to my lack of confidence. I'll wait for a few more comments from others but will accept your answer unless there's something compelling that follows.

Comment: Ok, i'm accepting this answer @Brian. Thanks. One last thing, storing the units that a marker was captured in is important to keep the transaction non-lossy and auditable but this would be stored in a separate field. No issues with the SQL then. Maybe I didn't understand your SQL comment though. The only issue I see would be if I store original UOM and original magnitude rather than original UOM and converted magnitude. To keep the query SQL simple the magnitude field must be a consistent unit.

Comment: @ken - Yes. That's what I was getting at. You'd want to keep conversions out of the SQL